# Designing a constructor or structure in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oop, constructor, structure

I am studying Visual Basic .NET (for an interview).

I have a question about proper data structure (maybe constructor, structure or other data structure).

For example,

1. We have maybe 10 or more TVs (TV1, TV2, TV3…..)

   - Each TV has one or three unique channels (low, mid, high) (for example, 45, 100, and 135)
   - Each channel (low, mid, and high) can choose black and white screen, color screen or both
2. Each TV has five kinds of frequency (Frq_1, Frq_2, etc.)

   - Each frequency (Frq_1, Frq_2, etc.) has seven unique frequency settings which is one pair of integer values. For example, Frq_1 -> <1,3>  Frq_2-><1,5> …..

I am beginner of VB.NET, so I am not really sure what and how to design the data structure.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: a class would be ideal - each of those is just a property

Comment: a [Constructor, or ctor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z08e49e(v=vs.90).aspx) is a procedure that runs when a class is created (instanced, actually).  It is nothing like a structure, its code, but some of those might be set in the class constructor like 1a or 1ai since it *sounds* like it doesnt change.  You'd end up with a List(Of TVClass) to handle the '10 or more' part

Answer (score 1):

The screen type can be described as an enum, the rest using classes and properties, e.g.

```
Enum Screen
    MonoChrome
    Color
    Both
End Enum

Class Channel
    Property Number As Integer
    Property Screen As Screen
End Class

MustInherit Class Channels
End Class

Class OneChannel
    Inherits Channels
    Property Channel As Channel
End Class

Class ThreeChannels
    Inherits Channels
    Property Low As Channel
    Property Medium As Channel
    Property High As Channel
End Class

Class Setting
    Property First As Integer
    Property Second As Integer
End Class

Class Frequency
    Property Set_1 As Setting
    Property Set_2 As Setting
    Property Set_3 As Setting
    Property Set_4 As Setting
    Property Set_5 As Setting
    Property Set_6 As Setting
    Property Set_7 As Setting
End Class

Class TV
    Property Channels As Channels
    Property Frq_1 As Frequency
    Property Frq_2 As Frequency
    Property Frq_3 As Frequency
    Property Frq_4 As Frequency
    Property Frq_5 As Frequency
End Class

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim tvs(10) As TV
        // ...
    End Sub
End Module
```